# Swipe Refresh Layout breaks recycler item template

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

Hi MvvmCross/Xamarin Devs,

I have ran into a problem which revolves around the MvxRecyclerView and the android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout. This problem occurs on Android using:

- Xamarin Version: 7.0.1.3 (Xamarin Business)
- SDK Tools Version: 25.1.7
- SDK Platform Tools Version: 24.0.1
- SDK Build Tools Version: 23.0.3
- MvvmCross V4.3.0.

So here's what's happening. I have an MvxRecyclerView which is bound to an observable collection, and has a custom template. I am also using a TemplateSelector to show a "loading cell" when we hit the bottom of the list. The MvxRecyclerList is wrapped in a android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout to implement the swipe to refresh pattern.

When the results load into the list it appears as it should, navigating back and coming back to the list works as well. The cell template layout looks exactly as it should. As you can see below.

[image]

However, when I do a pull to refresh and the data I'm waiting for finally returns the layout is "Broken", Everything is there, but it's messed up. See below

[image]

As if that's not weird enough, the cells that are broken swap everytime you do a pull to refresh.

[image]

Sometimes none are broken. The last thing to add is that the cells fix themselved when it's been recycled.

I have narrowed it down to the fact that the MvxRecyclerView is wrapped up in the SwipeRefreshLayout, without that there I can call the reload function multiple times without the cells bugging out once.

Any help or pointers on this would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE: ItemTemplate Xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:local="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="#fff">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">
    <Mvx.MvxImageView
        android:id="@+id/car_item_template_image_view"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:background="@drawable/image_placeholder"
        local:MvxBind="ImageUrl MainImageUrl" />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_item_template_make_text"
            android:text="Make"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_blue"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/car_item_template_title_text_size"
            local:MvxBind="Text Make, Converter=EmptyStringCheck"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView
            android:text="Model"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/car_item_template_model_text_width"
            android:layout_height="25dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_blue"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/car_item_template_make_text"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/car_item_template_price_text"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/car_item_template_title_text_size"
            local:MvxBind="Text Model, Converter=EmptyStringCheck"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:singleLine="true" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_item_template_price_text"
            android:text="Price"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/car_item_template_make_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:textColor="@color/theme_blue"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:textSize="@dimen/car_item_template_title_text_size"
            local:MvxBind="Text Price, Converter=IntToPrice" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_item_template_year_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_above="@+id/car_item_template_mileage_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Year"
            android:textSize="@dimen/car_item_template_detail_text_size"
            local:MvxBind="Text Year, Converter=EmptyShortCheck, ConverterParameter='No Year'" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_item_template_mileage_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/car_item_template_location_text"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Mileage"
            android:textSize="@dimen/car_item_template_detail_text_size"
            local:MvxBind="Text Mileage, Converter=IntToMileage, ConverterParameter='No Mileage'" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/car_item_template_location_text"
            android:text="Location"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:textSize="@dimen/car_item_template_detail_text_size"
            local:MvxBind="Text Location, Converter=EmptyStringCheck, ConverterParameter='No Location'" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@drawable/generic_graydivider" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your item template.

Comment: @Cheesebaron updated the question. Added in the Template xml

Comment: @Cheesebaron I'm doing with a workaround for now, see answer below. I still don't know what's causing it :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this is a workaround for the problem. As you see in my template above, the TextViews widths are all set to wrap_content. I changed it to fixed values and the problem is now not occurring anymore.

Unfortunately I still don't know what's causing the list to respond this way when contained in the SwipeRefreshLayout :( But this will do for now.